# 3D interpolation visualization with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation, visualisation, 3d-model, local-scene

I would like to use the result of a global polynomial interpolation as a base for visualizing a 3D model in the local scene view in ArcGIS Pro, but I always get back a flat layer in the local scene view.

I would like to do this to better show the trend of the interpolation on a 3D model.

Noticing that many examples of 3D interpolation models are done with TIN, I tried to convert the result of the GPI into a TIN, but still, I can only see a flat layer.
I also tried to convert the initial 2D point data into 3D points with the tool 'feature to 3D' and repeat the process, but it doesn’t work anyway.

Also, when I try to exaggerate the value, nothing changes.

Can someone suggest any efficient methodology?